# How to change the print window theme gray to black in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

How to change the print window theme gray to black  in uwp?

I want to change print window theme as black
any one known this related?

Please refer the images

[image]

Comment: Currently, there is no such api or setting to change the background color of print window to black, we can only customize the print options and settings in the print preview UI.

Comment: Can you please provide example?

Comment: For more information about how to customize the print preview UI, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/customize-the-print-preview-ui) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Printing/cs/Scenario3CustomOptions.xaml.cs) is an official sample, you can also check it. However, there is no such api to change the background color of print window to black.